# Ordered Lists with descriptions

Tags: html-lists

I'm writing an ordered list. For each element in the list, I'd like to have two lines. One for the name of the item and another for a description of the item.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item one</li>
            <li>An explanation of the item.</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item two</li>
            <li>An explanation of the item.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

It seems like a lot to achieve what I was looking for. Does anyone know a quicker way to pull this off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use a definition list (`<dl>`) instead of the inner ul.

```
<dl>
   <dt>Dog</dt>
   <dd>A carnivorous mammal of the family Canidae.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great, how did I miss it.

Comment: @uncollected: nothing says “thank you” like clicking the tick next to the answer!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h3>Item one</h3>
        <p>An explanation of the item.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Item two</h3>
        <p>An explanation of the item.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

(Replace `<h3>` with the appropriate level heading in that context in the document — or, if you’re using HTML5, wrap the `<ol>` in a `<section>` tag, and use `<h1>` in place of `<h3>`.)

Or do you really need an ordered list? If not, the [definition list](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) is the thing:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Item one</dt>
    <dd>An explanation of the item.</dd>

    <dt>Item two</dt>
    <dd>An explanation of the item.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: The definition list will be good for me. Thank you very much!